# Jackon 2.4.2 failing to deserialize valid date, even after specifying date format

Tags: java, json, date, jackson, deserialization

I am attempting to deserialize a JSON with a custom date format. It is failing, even though I have set a date format on the object mapper:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
```

Then I attempt to deserialize the following JSON using that mapper:

```
{
  "id": 11,
  "confirmed": false,
  "creationDate": "2015-04-20T22:27:41Z",
  "lastUpdateDate": "2015-04-20T22:27:41Z",
  "name": "test"
}
```

Using the line:

```
Test test = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Test.class);
```

and it fails with:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2015-04-20T22:27:41Z': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2015-04-20T22:27:41Z': Unparseable date: "2015-04-20T22:27:41Z")
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I can't seem to figure out what I am missing...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`. `Z` is for an RFC 822 time zone, and Z is not such a timezone. `X` is for a ISO 8601 time zone, and Z is such a timezone.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html